# How can I surpress GCC warnings for no prototypes for interrupt routines when -Wmissing-prototypes is used?

Tags: c, embedded, compiler-warnings, interrupt, mplab

I'm writing embedded code in C using MPLABX (IDE for Microchip products) and the XC16 compiler (which is based on GCC).

I'm using `-Wmissing-prototypes` to make sure that I have prototypes for all of my functions. My problem is that I have a lot of interrupt service routines, and this is causing the compiler to complain about missing prototypes for these as well.

Because the ISR functions are never called by the user software directly, I don't want to put a prototype for them anywhere in my code.

Is there any way to show warnings for missing prototypes, *except* for interrupt service routines (i.e., functions tagged with `__attribute__((interrupt,auto_psv))`)?

Comment: Why don't you just make prototypes right beside the definitions?

Comment: I've thought about that, but since I'm not too familiar with gcc I thought that there might be some cleaner way that I didn't know about. If I was to do it this way, do I only include the attribute tag on the prototype, or both the prototype and definition?

Comment: I don't think it matters.  But if you want it only in one spot, I think the prototype is the place.  I have a hazy memory of having a problem with `always_inline` needing to be in one place or the other, but I don't remember which.

Answer (score 3):

I followed Carl Norum's advice and simply added the function prototypes right above the function definitions.

As an example:

```
void __attribute__((interrupt,auto_psv)) _SPI2ErrInterrupt(void);
void _SPI2ErrInterrupt(void)
{
    // Do ISR stuff...
}
```